# Operator in Function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have the folloing code

```
var func = function(a, b, c) {
    //Some Code
};

$('whatever').on( function(e){
    func( e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.target);  //<- WTF?
});
```

What does the operator in the function parameter mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "operator"?

Comment: http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510 there is a good explanation.

Comment: You can use any expression as argument for a function call. The result of the expression will then be passed to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` returns the first non-truthy expression or the last evaluated expression, if both of them are truthy.

So basically, you are making sure that `e.originalEvent` exists and if it does, the value of `e.originalEvent.target` is passed as the first parameter to `func`. If `e.originalEvent` doesn't exist, it would be `undefined`. In that case, `undefined` would be passed to `a` and `e.originalEvent.target` would not be evaluated at all.

Consider the following expressions

```
console.log(1 && 2);
# 2
console.log(null && 2);
# null
console.log(undefined && 2);
# undefined
console.log(0 && 2);
# 0
```

**Note:** Since you are passing only one argument, `b` and `c` will be `undefined`, by default.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the explanation of how && works - I thought it just returned true/false depending on whether the arguments passed the expression.  I didn't know it could return the last value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple expression. The argument passed to the function will be the result of the `AND`-ing of the two values.

In this case, if `e.originalEvent` is truthy (not `null`, `false` or `undefined`), it will evaluate to `e.originalEvent.target`.

Comment: Ah, so its just a boolean expression, and the "a" parameter of "func()" is the last value of the && expression.  Gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then `e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.target` is the first parameter as `a`, `b` and `c` will be `undefined`.

`a && b` returns `a` if `a` is falsy value, otherwise returns `b`.